# Is calling a method on an object during destruction call from another thread undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++

Is calling a method on an object during destructor call from another thread undefined behaviour (I guarantee that required fields are still alive and accessible and access to them synchronized)?

[c++14 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (12.7.4) says:

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction,
>   the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.

Trying to understand whether it's valid to have a pattern where object A owns thread B and thread B could call a callback on object A at any moment. The destructor of object A would join the thread before destroying any relevant state.

Relevant code sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void reg() {
    thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
      while (a_ < 10) {
        pr();
      }
    });
  }

  void pr() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mt_);
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    a_++;
  }

  ~A() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mt_);
    std::cout << "Destruction started\n";
    lock.unlock();

    thread_.join();
  }

  int a_{0};
  std::mutex mt_;
  std::thread thread_;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.reg();
}
```

PS: I'm aware that I need to synchronize access to fields and be careful about stopping callbacks after leaving destructor body.

PPS: Also, the same question is taking place for virtual methods? Is it possible that virtual call be dispatched to overriden method in derived class (which data has been already destroyed)? According to the cite above, it should not. But i'm still not sure can we apply it to multithreaded scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, can you show an example in actual code? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of a **data race**. Yes, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: As long as you haven't reached the end of the destructor block it is legal to use any member of the object.  If you had a example we could look we could probably give you a better answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't think it's a definition of a data race. Added example.

Comment: It looks like the answer is no, it's well defined, because:
`Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2).`

Comment: <shrug> -- your newly added example is **much narrower** than your question. If your destructor and your callback don't do anything that creates a data race, then, yes, it's okay; otherwise, no. But that's not helpful, because you have no way of knowing whether that's true. The text you quote, [class.cdtor]/4, does not address multi-threaded applications. For that you have to look at [intro.multithread].

Comment: "But that's not helpful, because you have no way of knowing whether that's true."
why is it so? I can rely on the implementation of destructor i.e. the same way as in the example.

Comment: @PeteBecker one more question if I may, "then, yes, it's okay" why is it so? I understand your reasoning that the standard doesn't specify anything in 12.7.4 paragraph about multithreaded and we can conclude from here that it is undefined indeed. We need some other paragraph to say that this is ok. Also, the question will the virtual call be dispatched properly (as 12.7.4 suggests)? Or maybe these lookups can lead to data race i.e. on vtable)? can we guarantee that the call will not be dispatched to overrides in derived classes (fields of which are already destroyed)? what's about nonvirtual?

Comment: [intro.multithread] has the critical text about accessing an object simultaneously from multiple threads. It defines a "data race", essentially, as two or more simultaneous accesses, at least one of which is a write. When that happens, the behavior is undefined. In a destructor, in addition to the obvious accesses in the code you've written, there are compiler-generated accesses to destroy objects and (too much implementation detail coming up) to adjust the vtable pointer.

Comment: "there are compiler-generated accesses to destroy objects" - they will be called after leaving destructor and it's guaranteed by standard imo. I am not planning to leave destructor until all other subscribers will be unsubscribed, which will guarantee that no further calls happen after leaving destructor body or some synchronization primitive in a body which probably will block destructor until I clear every reference to the object. The question is the call itself after entering destructor well defined? And will this call be dispatched properly as in one threaded scenario?

Comment: @PeteBecker continuing previous comment. We can assume there is no data race on fields (or no access to fields at all, because the question is about the call itself and not about validity of my data synchronization inside the call). We will no leave destructor body until we will be able guarantee stop of all other accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, yes, it is undefined behavior and very unsafe.

The one notable exception is if the method in question doesn't need to read or write the state of the object (`virtual` methods count as "needing to read state", even if the method itself doesn't read or write state). If that's the case, then calling the method on it won't result in undefined behavior.

It'll still be unsafe though, and you should try as much as possible to prevent it from happening.

Comment: This "notable exception" seems like, at best, an extremely narrow corner case, most likely utterly useless.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, which is why I led the answer with "Most of the time, this is undefined and unsafe". I feel there is value in acknowledging the possible exceptions to this rule.